# Can't find this book

Tags: machine-learning, mathematics, books

I came across the most comprehensive ML Mathematics book (700+ pages) with sections on Probability, Calculus, Linear Algebra and Mathematical Foundations of the famous tricks in Deep Learning on Twitter about a year ago. It was not available in print yet can anyone give me a clue as to which it could be? I can't seem to find it. P.S. It is not Deep Learning by Ian Goodfellow.

Answer (score 2):

This is an impossible to answer question as stated.

...That being said, I imagine you mean either

"Deep Learning"

- Goodfellow et al

or

"Algebra, Topology, Differential Calculus, and Optimization Theory For Computer Science and Machine Learning"

- Jean Gallier & Jocelyn Quaintance